# Kibana. Как настроить разные индексы для логов

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Имеется стэк `ELK`, в который собираются логи приложений и метрик для них. В `logstash` настроен фильтр, который добавляет префикс для метрик:

```
filter {
    if [logger_name] =~ "metrics" {
        kv {
            source => "message"
            field_split => ", "
            prefix => "metric_"
        }
...
}
```

Необходимо как-то отделить логи от "метрик", чтобы в `Kibana` настроить визуализацию по разным индексам. Подскажите, возможно ли такое реализовать и куда копать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказлось достаточно просто. Нужно разделить индексы в конфиге `logstash`:

```
output {
    ...
    if [logger_name] =~ "metrics" {
            elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}:${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}"]
                index => "metrics-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            }
        } else {
            elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}:${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}"]
                index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            }
        }
}
```

Затем в `Kibana` добавить новый `index pattern`